# custom ImageView with property and mvvmcross binding

Tags: binding, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a Xamarin Android porject with MvvmCross.
For testing, I added a CustomImageView with a HslBackground property

```
public class CustomImageView : ImageView
{
    private HslColor _hslBackground;

    public CustomImageView (Context context)
        : base(context) { }

    public CustomImageView (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        : base(context, attrs) { }

    public HslColor HslBackground
    {
        get { return _hslBackground; }
        set
        {
            if (_hslBackground != value)
            {
                _hslBackground = value;

                byte r, g, b;
                value.ToRGB(out r, out g, out b);
                this.Background = new ColorDrawable(new Color(r, g, b));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Example.MVVM.Droid.Controls.CustomImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/colorView"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        local:MvxBind="HslBackground HslColor" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I added breakpoints to the `HslBackground` property, but either getter nor setter is called. Any idea what to do? I am using the latest MvvmCross from Nuget.

**Update 1**:
I see in the log

```
MvxBind:Error:  0.99 View type not found - md56c24830106cce038b53f4325e503c583.CustomImageView
MvxBind:Error:  0.99 View type not found - md56c24830106cce038b53f4325e503c583.CustomImageView
[art] JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md56c24830106cce038b53f4325e503c583.CustomImageView
```

**Update 2**
Binding the property to `TextView` works

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    local:MvxBind="Text HslColor" />
```

Comment: What does trace say? What's the ViewModel property you are binding to? (Can you include that code in the question?) What happens if you bind the viewmodel property to the Text of a label?

Comment: The ViewModel has a public property; I never raise any propertychange event, but the value is set. That should be enough during initialization. I will post log and view model tomorrow when i am back at work

Comment: @Stuart I added some log output

Comment: @esskar you are using `Example.MVVM.Droid.Controls.CustomImageView` as for the View tag. I have actually never used anything that the class name itself e.g. `<MyOwnView />`. Maybe it's worth a try only with `<CustomImageView />`?

Comment: @Nikola he would get an Exception when inflating the view, so nope...

Comment: @Nikola Thanks. That actually works. Strange but ok!

Comment: Sounds like this is all down to Xamarin's latest changes - look for info about `[Register("view-name")]` in recent releases

Comment: @Cheesebaron I have started with Xamarin and MvvmCross in September 2014 and I have never had to write the full namespace of my custom classes. I don't know if this is correct or not, but never had any problems with inflating or not finding the views